# ASP.Net creating a formatted printable report

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, format, report

I have a client that is requiring their claims (entered online) to be printed out through their web application, with formatting. What is the most efficient means of doing this?

Comment: formatting such as boxes around sections, bolding of headers, solid lines, tables with cell borders. The online claim form has a bunch of information that is not required on the print out so doing the mornal print popup would not be feasible, hense the reason I am asking the question, if it was that simple I wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: +1 Cannot see why this question was down voted

Answer (score -2, accepted):

used a simple web page and print web page function

Answer (score 4):

If you're using good HTML markup and CSS to render the UI (which is more likely if you're using ASP.NET MVC than it is if you're using WebForms), you can exploit a useful feature that allows an additional CSS Stylesheet to be used specifically for printing, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

In this stylesheet, you override the settings from the main CSS stylesheet to reformat the HTML as you need. That may include hiding unwanted text using

```
display:none;
```

in the applicable styles.

You'll need to be pretty competent with CSS, in my opinion, but it's highly efficient - there's no code to write. You display the data on-screen and when you print it, it comes out differently.